# Javascript GET callback function not defined on server response

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have created a version that holds everything that is relevant to my question :

```
//new version doesn't work ->

function global_function(server_response){}

function Constructor(global_function){
    this.local_reference_to_global_function=global_function;}
Constructor.prototype.api_function(){
    //this.localreference_to_global_function("test"); // works
    //global_function("test"); // works
    xmlhttp=XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        this.local_reference_to_global_function(xmlhttp.responseText)} 
        // does not work on asynchronuous callback
        // probably scope/visibility/closure lifetime/whatever is wrong
        // and I need to understand what is wrong to fix it in my code .
        // firebug said that "this.local_reference_to_global_function is not a function"
        // the first 2 calls in this function work
        //so I am puzzled that this doesn't
    xmlhttp.open("GET",...);
    xmlhttp.send();}

var derivativeConstructor;
function server_query(){
    if(derivativeConstrucror===undefined){
        var derivativeConstructor=new Constructor(global_function);}
    derivativeConstructor.api_function();}

//old version works but clutters my code so I don't want it ->
//the actual code saves more lines of code
//and has better visibility
// so it's worth it
//unlike this example

function server_query(){xmlhttp=XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        global_function(xmlhttp.responseText)}
    xmlhttp.open("GET",...);
    xmlhttp.send();} // this worked and all the rest should be practically unchanged

// where it all get's called from - should be unchanged between versions ->

<form action="" method="GET" onsubmit="(function(){return false;});">
    <input type="button" value="TEST" onclick="server_query();">
</form>
```

When I say the old version that I want to change works I mean it . My problem was that I didn't post my entire code the first time so people have the impression that I didn't try in the first place and then aren't looking further at what I actually asked .
Now I also tried to simplify things to eliminate the clutter around the place where I think the problem is , so this is not the actual code and may not workd copy pasted in a browser - there may be "little problems" . I am only intereste with the question I asked : where did I go wrong with function visibility/closure variable visibility/variable lifetime/whatever and how I can fix it .

Old version of the question : got me branded as someone that doesn't define his functions by the 2 people that answered/commented ->

I have this javascript code that is supposed to simplify the creation of a server GET :

```
function Generic_server_request(
        server_location,
        server_file,
        client_callback_function){
    this.server_location=server_location;
    this.server_file=server_file;
    this.query_parameters="";
    this.client_callback_function=client_callback_function;}
Generic_server_request.prototype
.server_request=function(){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState===4
            && xmlhttp.status===200)
                this.client_callback_function(
                    xmlhttp.responseText);
        else if((xmlhttp.status!==200) ||
                xmlhttp.status===200 &&
                xmlhttp.readyState!==2 &&
                xmlhttp.readyState!==3)
            alert("readystate "+xmlhttp.readyState
                +" status "+xmlhttp.status);}
    xmlhttp.open("GET",
        this.server_location+
        this.server_file+
        this.query_parameters,
        true);
    xmlhttp.send();}
Generic_server_request.prototype
.set_query_parameters=function(query_parameters){
    this.query_parameters=query_parameters}

function server_querry(input){
    if(query_request_manager === undefined){
        query_request_manager=new Generic_server_request(
            "http://localhost/cgi-bin/",
            "querry_handler.php",
            status_text);}
    query_request_manager.set_query_parameters("?input="+input);
    query_request_manager.server_request();}
```

The problem is that when the server response arrives I get exactly this error in the firebug console : "this.client_callback_function is not a function" .
I could use some help to understand what is going on with the scope .

EDIT I had a previous version that did everything that should achieved with Generic... and server_querry(input) in a previous version of server_querry(input) and status_text is very much running ok in other parts of the code atm so that is not the problem . And the code that uses server_status and server_status are unmodified from the previous intended functionality .

Also something like this works as intended :

function Generic_server_request(...,client_callback_function){
    ...
    this.client_callback_function=client_callback_function;
    client_callback_function("test");//works
    this.client_callback_function("test");//works

Comment: It is defined , I just didn't post the entire code .

Answer (score 1):

When you create your request object you use:

```
new Generic_server_request(
 "http://localhost/cgi-bin/",
 "querry_handler.php",
 status_text
);
```

But in constructor your function described as:

```
function Generic_server_request(
 server_location,
 server_file,
 client_callback_function
)
```

So instead of `client_callback_function` you pass `status_text` (that is not a function)

Comment: That is actually the function prototype name and status_text is defined as a global variable .

Comment: Can you show your `status_text` function declaration?
----
And are you sure, that you have only one variable (especially in global scope) which name as `status_text`?

Comment: Did you see that? http://lpar.ath0.com/2010/10/14/javascript-when-is-a-function-not-a-function/
http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my initial problem though I created another , though that is good for another question if I get no new suggestions .
This is my starting point at the moment relative to the generic look of the code above 
(top code block) :

```
function global_function(server_response){}

function Constructor(global_function){
    this.local_reference_to_global_function=global_function;}
    //still doesn't work but now I intuitively get why it doesn't work
    //apparently this.xmlhttp is created new instead of being the one in api_function
    //and the 2 are not shared through the Constructor(global_function) environment

    //I could use some help from someone that would tell me
    //how to make minimal changes to get this.xmlhttp in this example
    //(this.xmlhttp in prototype.callback and prototype.api_function)
    //to reference the same object
    //or make equivalent minimal changes to other parts of the code

Constructor.prototype.callback=function(){
    this.xmlhttp.local_reference_to_global_function(this.xmlhttp.responseText);};
Constructor.prototype.api_function=function(){
    this.xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    this.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=this.callback();
    //xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    //    this.local_reference_to_global_function(xmlhttp.responseText)} 
    // old version accesses local_reference_to_global_function
    // inside onreadystatechange function's new environment a new object
    // which is where I was stumped initially
    // new variable environment created that I didn't get
    xmlhttp.open("GET",...);
    xmlhttp.send();}

var derivativeConstructor;
function server_query(){
    if(derivativeConstrucror===undefined){
        var derivativeConstructor=new Constructor(global_function);}
    derivativeConstructor.api_function();}
```